# js-comint mode on Emacs: NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: javascript, emacs, debian, rhino

I installed js-comint mode on Emacs 24. Now when i try to execute `run-js`, it throws the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/mozilla/javascript/tools/shell/Main
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.mozilla.javascript.tools.shell.Main
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
Could not find the main class: org.mozilla.javascript.tools.shell.Main. Program will exit.

Process js exited abnormally with code 1
```

The variable `inferior-js-program-command` is `"/usr/bin/java org.mozilla.javascript.tools.shell.Main"`, and for some reason it doesn't work. What should i do to be able to run inferior javascript process in Emacs? If the above error means that i don't have some Java library, what package should install in Debian?

I use Linux Mint Debian Edition (corresponds to Debian testing). I have `openjdk-6-jre` installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, i've found a workaround. I installed `rhino` package on my Debian and put `"/usr/bin/rhino"` in variable `inferior-js-program-command`, now Emacs successfully runs inferior javascript process. However i'm still interested, why didn't `/usr/bin/java org.mozilla.javascript.tools.shell.Main` didn't work on my system.

Comment: Because you don't have Java and/or the required library?

Comment: I found your question having the same problem. My workaround was the same as you, except that I replaced the default inferior-js-program-command by "/usr/bin/node"...